# get jquery object from jquery collection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery 1.11.1.

Once I selected a collection using a selector, i.e `var objs = $('.selector_class')`
how can I get jquery element from that element. 
I tried `objs[0]` and `objs.get(0)`. Both give javascript object.
is there a way to access one jquery object directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `.eq(index)`

```
$('.selector_class').eq(0)
```

[doc](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Answer (score 0):

With objs[0] and objs.get(0) you're getting the DOM element, not the jQuery object.

You can convert the DOM object to a jQuery element by wrapping it in $(), or get the jQuery elements directly:

```
<div class="selector_class">Text1</div>
<div class="selector_class">Text2</div>
<div class="selector_class">Text3</div>

<script>
    $(function () {
        var collection = $(".selector_class");
        var a = collection.eq(0).text();
        var b = collection.eq(1).text();
        var c = collection.eq(2).text();

        console.log("a: " + a + " => b: " + b + " => c: " + c);
        // shows: a: Text1 => b: Text2 => c: Text3
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using `.eq( index )`

```
index
```

Above is of Type: **Integer**

An integer indicating the **0-based** position of the element.

`.eq()` method constructs a new jQuery object from one element within that set.

When it is provided with an integer, it gives the position of this element in the set.